# Using On Blur to Call a Function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have a web page update a value when the text field loses focus. I have tried a number of different suggested variations for the onblur event but nothing seems to work as expected. Currently I have the onblur in the html code on line 59

```
<input name="qty1" id="qty1" size="8" value="0" onBlur="productCost()" />
```

and I have tried to make the correction in the script as well.

function productCosts()

```
{
    var totalMap = document.getElementById("qty1").onblur();
    totalMap.value = ("qty1") * ("price1");
    //$("#cost1").html (totalMap.toFixed(2));
    alert(totalMap)

    //var totalPlanner = ('qty2') * ('price2');
    //var totalHiker = ('qty3') * ('price3');
}
```

I have created a fiddle to show the entire program. http://jsfiddle.net/Jn6LQ/ Any help would be really greatly appreciated.

Comment: I removed jQuery tag from question because you are obviously not using it

Comment: he's using it in the fiddle....

Comment: @sjkm No, he's not using it, he's 'redefining' `$` btw

Comment: sorry my fault, you're obviously right!

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** In the below, `$` is **not** jQuery, the OP is using it as a shortcut for `getElementById`.

The line

```
totalMap.value = ("qty1") * ("price1");
```

multiplies the **string** `"qty1"` with the **string** `"price1"`. Perhaps you meant to look up the elements, and then get their values:

```
totalMap.value = $("qty1").value * $("price1").value;
```

Separately, using `onXyz` attributes is usually not best practice. Instead:

```
$("qty1").onblur = productCosts;
$("price1").onblur = productCosts;

function productCosts() {
    var value = $("qty1").value * $("price1").value;
    $("cost1").innerHTML = value.toFixed(2);
}
```

(There I'm assuming the price can be changed as well, but that may not be the case on your page.)

Looking at the fiddle, though, you have a much bigger problem: You want to do that for multiple lines. Using `id` values to do that is going to make for gainly, over-large code. Instead, use a class on each input, and then relate it to the other inputs in the row using the fact they're all in the same row.

```
function productCosts() {
    var row   = this.parentNode.parentNode,
        qty   = row.querySelector(".qty"),
        price = row.querySelector(".price"),
        cost  = row.querySelector(".cost"),
        value = qty.value * price.value;
    cost.innerHTML = value.toFixed(2);
}

var list, i;
list = document.querySelectorAll(".qty, .price");
for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    list[i].onblur = productCosts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with jQuery

```
$('#qty1').bind('blur', productCosts)
```

or with JS

```
document.getElementById('qty1').addEventListener('blur', productCosts)
```

Answer (score -1):

jQuery.blur() looks like what you're looking for:

```
$('#qty1').blur(function(){
    alert('here');
});
```